# bash: Possible to require double Ctrl-c to to exit a script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

**End-goal:** BASH script that is waiting for background jobs to finish does not abort on first `Ctrl-c`; instead, it requires a second `Ctrl-c` to quit.

I'm well aware of how the BASH-builtin `trap` works. You can either:

1. Use it to ignore a signal altogether (e.g., `trap '' 2`) ... or
2. Use it to have arbitrary commands executed before a signals original function is allowed to happen (e.g., `trap cmd 2`, where `cmd` is run before the parent script will be interrupted due to `SIGINT`)

So the question boils down to this:

> How can I effectively combine **1** & **2** together, i.e., prevent the end-result a signal would lead to (**1** -- e.g., stop script cancelling due to `SIGINT`) while also making that signal cause something else (**2** -- e.g., increment a counter, check the counter and conditionally either print a warning or exit).

Put more simply:

> How can I make a signal do something else entirely; not just insert a job before it does its thing.

Here's some example code to demonstrate what I'm aiming at; however, it of course doesn't work -- because `trap` can only do **1** or **2** from above.

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -i number_of_times_trap_triggered
cleanup_bg_jobs() {
    number_of_times_trap_triggered+=1
    if [[ ${number_of_times_trap_triggered} -eq 1 ]]; then
        echo "There are background jobs still running"
        echo "Hit Ctrl-c again to cancel all bg jobs & quit"
    else
        echo "Aborting background jobs"
        for pid in ${bg_jobs}; do echo "  Killing ${pid}"; kill -9 ${pid}; done
    fi
}
f() { sleep 5m; }
trap cleanup_bg_jobs 2
bg_jobs=
for job in 1 2 3; do
    f &
    bg_jobs+=" $!"
done
wait
```

So this is the output you end up getting when you press `Ctrl-c` once.

```
[rsaw:~]$ ./zax 
^CThere are background jobs still running
Hit Ctrl-c again to cancel all bg jobs & quit
[rsaw:~]$ ps axf|tail -6 
24569 pts/3    S      0:00 /bin/bash ./zax
24572 pts/3    S      0:00  \_ sleep 5m
24570 pts/3    S      0:00 /bin/bash ./zax
24573 pts/3    S      0:00  \_ sleep 5m
24571 pts/3    S      0:00 /bin/bash ./zax
24574 pts/3    S      0:00  \_ sleep 5m
```

Of course I could modify that to clean up the jobs on the first `Ctrl-c`, but that's not what I want. I want to stop BASH from quiting after the first trap is triggered ... until it's triggered a second time.

PS: Target platform is Linux (I couldn't care less about POSIX compliance) with BASH v4+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A colleague (Grega) just gave me a solution which ... well I can't believe I didn't think of it first.

> *"My approach would ... be to lay it off for long enough, possibly forever, using a function that just never returns or something (another wait?), so that the second handler can do its job properly."*

For the record, `wait` would not work here. (Recursive.) However, adding a `sleep` command to my original code's `cleanup_bg_jobs()` function would take care of it .. but would lead to orphaned processes. So I leveraged process groups to ensure that all children of the script really do get killed. Simplified example for posterity:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -i count=
handle_interrupt() {
    count+=1
    if [[ ${count} -eq 1 ]]; then
        echo "Background jobs still running"
        echo "Hit Ctrl-c again to cancel all bg jobs & quit"
        sleep 1h
    else
        echo "Aborting background jobs"
        pkill --pgroup 0
    fi
}
f() { tload &>/dev/null; }
trap handle_interrupt 2
for job in 1 2 3; do
    f &
done
wait
```

Answer (score 9):

I had a slightly different use case, and wanted to leave the solution here, as Google led me to this topic. You can keep running a command, and allow the user to restart it with one `CTRL+C`, and kill it with double `CTRL+C` in the following manner:

```
trap_ctrlC() {
    echo "Press CTRL-C again to kill. Restarting in 2 second"
    sleep 2 || exit 1
}

trap trap_ctrlC SIGINT SIGTERM

while true; do  
    ... your stuff here ...
done
```

Comment: this is beautiful. tks

Comment: It appears more people are here to view this answer than to view the actual answer to the question :)

Answer (score 5):

I did something like this [here](https://github.com/infoforcefeed/OlegDB/blob/master/run_server.sh) and it mostly breaks down to this:

```
    ATTEMPT=0
handle_close() {
    if [ $ATTEMPT -eq 0 ]; then
        ATTEMPT=1
        echo "Shutdown."
    else
        echo "Already tried to shutdown. Killing."
        exit 0
    fi
}
trap handle_close SIGINT SIGTERM
```

You can set a variable in your handler that you can check again next time it is trapped.

Comment: Usually in this case, the two Ctrl+C are required to be continuous to stop the program. So, a better solution should set ATTEMP back to 0 when a key down is captured.

Comment: Thanks for trying Wally, but what you're offering doesn't actually answer what I asked. It will shutdown after the first `echo Shutdown.` command runs.

Comment: PS: I updated my post with some of my own example code to show that `trap` doesn't work how you think it works. (Unless I'm insane.)

Comment: Seems that two signals are generated when Ctrl+C is pressed. Funny.

Comment: It's simply doing what I described in the original question: when set up `trap` to run a command, it doesn't run that command INSTEAD of performing the usual action that such a signal would cause; it runs that command BEFORE performing the usual signal action.

Answer (score 0):

> 2. Use it to have arbitrary commands executed before a signals original function is allowed to happen (e.g., trap cmd 2, where cmd is run *before the parent script will be interrupted due to SIGINT)*

The italicized part of the above is incorrect.  A trap handler is run **instead of** letting SIGINT (or whatever) interrupt the process.  More accurately:

- the default action of SIGINT (and of most, but not all, other signals) is to terminate the process
- `trap "command" SIGINT` causes `command` to be run instead of (not *as well as*) the default action

So with your SIGINT handler installed, the SIGINT doesn't interrupt the entire script.  But it **does** interrupt the `wait` command.  When the trap handler finishes, the script resumes after the `wait`, i.e. it falls off the end and exits normally.  You can see this by adding some debugging code:

```
echo Waiting
wait
echo Back from wait
exit 55                   # Arbitrary value that wouldn't otherwise occur
```

This version produces the following:

```
$ foo
Waiting
^CThere are background jobs still running
Hit Ctrl-c again to cancel all bg jobs & quit
back from wait
$ echo $?
55
$
```

What you need to do is repeat the `wait` after the handler returns.  This version:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -i number_of_times_trap_triggered
cleanup_bg_jobs() {
    number_of_times_trap_triggered+=1
    if [[ ${number_of_times_trap_triggered} -eq 1 ]]; then
        echo "There are background jobs still running"
        echo "Hit Ctrl-c again to cancel all bg jobs & quit"
    else
        echo "Aborting background jobs"
        for pid in ${bg_jobs}; do echo "  Killing ${pid}"; kill -9 ${pid}; done
        exit 1
    fi
}
f() { sleep 5m; }
trap cleanup_bg_jobs 2
bg_jobs=
for job in 1 2 3; do
    f &
    bg_jobs+=" $!"
done

while [ 1 ]; do
    echo Waiting
    wait
    echo Back from wait
done
```

does as you requested:

```
$ ./foo
Waiting
^CThere are background jobs still running
Hit Ctrl-c again to cancel all bg jobs & quit
Back from wait
Waiting
^CAborting background jobs
  Killing 24154
  Killing 24155
  Killing 24156
$
```

Notes:

- I've left in the debugging stuff; obviously you'd remove it in production
- The handler now does `exit 1` after killing off the subprocesses.  That's what breaks out of the infinite main loop